PennyLane Certificate Challenge
I am trying to solve this problem: https://pennylane.ai/challenges/intro_to_pennylane/
Here is what I got so far:
def W(params):
 # Put your code here
    num_wires = len(params[0])  
    for i in range(num_wires):
        qml.RY(params[0, i], wires=i)  
        if i < num_wires - 1:
            qml.CNOT(wires=[i, i+1])  
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, num_wires-1]) 

def S(g, x, num_wires):
# Put your code here
    for i in range(num_wires):
        qml.exp(qml.Hermitian(g.matrix, wires=[i]), coeff=x)

dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=3)
@qml.qnode(dev, expansion_strategy = "device")

def quantum_model(param_set, g, x):
# Put your code here
    num_wires = len(param_set[0][0])
    for i, params in enumerate(param_set):
        W(params)  
        S(g, x, num_wires)  

    return qml.probs(wires=0)  

The error I get is Failure message: Runtime Error: Failed to execute run() function: 'function' object has no attribute 'shape'. Thank you for helping!

The parameter g in your function S is of type qml.generator, which as you can see from the documentation, is a function, so you need to evaluate it it as g() to return the actual operator it is supposed to generate.
In this particular case, you also need to pass to g() a wire number, which will then return a qml.PauliX gate with that wire number associated with it. e.g., if you run g(0), you would get the object: PauliX(wires=[0]).
You can then completely avoid running qml.Hermitian() because you already have a gate associated with a wire, so you can simply exponentiate it: qml.exp(g(some_wire), coeff=some_coeff).
Just FYI, your coefficient for the exponentiation is wrong and your W function doesn't look right.

Thanks! I changed S into
for i in range(num_wires):         qml.exp(g(i), coeff=1j * x)
But I still struggle with W:
`num_layers = len(params)  # Number of layers (rows in params)
num_wires = len(params[0])  # Number of qubits (columns in params)
for layer in range(num_layers):
    for qubit in range(num_wires):
        qml.RY(params[layer][qubit], wires=qubit)
    
    for qubit in range(num_wires - 1):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[qubit, qubit + 1])
    
    qml.CNOT(wires=[0, num_wires - 1])`

